# AWS Glue: Get list of objects read by create_dynamic_frame.from_options

Tags: python, aws-glue

I'm using `create_dynamic_frame.from_options` to read CSV files into a Glue Dynamic Dataframe. My Glue job is using bookmark and `from_options` has both a transformation ctx configured and recursive search.

```
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options("s3", 
    {
        "paths": [
            "s3://bucket/files/"
        ],
        "recurse" : True
    },
    transformation_ctx = "example"
)
```

`s3://bucket/files` contains multiple CSVs. Is there a way to get a list of which objects were actually read? As I'm using bookmarks, files which have already been processed would be 'ignored'. These ignored files should be omitted from the list of read objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this: `dyf.toDF().withColumn("input_file", input_file_name()).select("input_file").distinct().show()`

Comment: Looks promising! Trying it out now.

Comment: Worked a treat! Cheers

Comment: One observation... If you're reading data with 'groupFiles': 'inPartition' then this no longer works. 'input_file_name' becomes blank.